# How to use ajax to post to kintone endpoint using AWS lambda and nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, ajax, aws-lambda

This is my first Stack Overflow post. I'm bumping into a wall trying to hit an API to add records into a Kintone App. I'm using ajax to send to AWS lambda function that uses nodejs. I know my AWS api gateway is working. I just can't figure out why the JSON object is not posting to the add record end point.

**Here is my JSON object:**

```
body: {
    app: 1,
    record: {
        Text: {
            value: 'Sample'
        },
        Number: {
            value: 1
       }
    }
}
```

**Here is my ajax post:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://my-aws-endpoint/add-record',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ body })
    // data: body
}).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**Here is my nodejs:**

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var https = require('https');
var DOMAIN = 'mydomain.com';
var AUTH_VALUE = 'myauthvalue;
var headers = { 
    'api-token': 'myapitoken', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    var postData = querystring.stringify(
        event.body
    );
    var options = {
        hostname: DOMAIN,
        port: 443,
        path: '/k/v1/add-record.json',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers
    };

    var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
        var data = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        context.done(null, JSON.parse(data));
    })
});
req.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write(postData);

req.end();};
```

**And this the response I'm getting:**

```
{code: "CB_IJ01", id: "FyttteBzB4eDaWEwoNUO", message: "Invalid JSON string."}
```

In advance thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing, please try encoding the body using JSON.stringify.

The part,
`data: JSON.stringify({ body })`,
You might be seeing the error because it has the "{}'s".
Change it to,
`data:JSON.stringify(body)`

Thanks